# Are there more convenient charts than Riemannian normal coordinate chart?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be an arbitrary smooth Riemannian manifold of $n$ dimensional and $p_0\in M$. $\nabla$ denotes the Levi Civita connection.

It is well known that there is a coordinate chart around $p_0$ s.t. 
\begin{eqnarray}
& g_{ij}(p_0)=\delta_{ij}\\
& \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(p_0)=0\ \ \ (i,j=1,\cdots, n). 
\end{eqnarray}
"Riemannian normal coordinate chart centered at $p_0$" is one of them.

Can we take a coordinate chart $(U;x^1,\cdots,x^n)$ around $p_0$ s.t. 
\begin{eqnarray}
& g_{ij}(p_0)=\delta_{ij}\\
& \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(p_0)=0\\
& \sum_{k=1}^n\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}}\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(p_0)=0\\
-(i,j=1,\cdots, n)?
\end{eqnarray}